# SQL fill empty values in a column based on case when selection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

So basically what I want to achieve is that if four columns are empty, one column contains a 1 as value and one column contains 0, then I want to entries in one column meeting the conditions with a default value (0.06077).

Meaning: IF COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D IS NULL and COL_E = 0 AND COL_F = 0 then fill the rows in COL_A which meet these conditions with a default value of 0.06077.

I tried the following:

```
, CASE WHEN COL_A IS NULL AND COL_B IS NULL AND COL_C IS NULL AND COL_D IS NULL 
AND COL_E = 0 AND COL_F = 1 THEN NVL(COL_A, 0.06077) END
```

The following did fill the entries meeting my set conditions. Anyone knows a potential sollution?

Comment: "did not work" isn't very helpful; are you getting an error, or just not the result you expected? Sample data and your current and expected results would be helpful. It isn't entirely clear which column you want to be 0 and which you want to be 1, so maybe you have those the wrong way round. [It seems to roughly work though.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a191afdbeb992b68adb59b40eeffe4b5) (And why are you using `NVL()` when you already *know* that `COL_A` is null? Or is that supposed to refer to a different column?)

Comment: Please, check how [`nvl` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html#GUID-3AB61E54-9201-4D6A-B48A-79F4C4A034B2) works and then rewrite your code again. If condition of `case` expression evaluates to `TRUE` then of course `col_a` is null and `nvl` is meaningless. Also please post *entire* SQL statement, not some part of it

Comment: Instead of `NVL(COL_A, 0.06077)` use just `0.06077` since `COL_A` is `NULL`. Also you may need an ELSE part in the CASE epression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IF COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D IS NULL and COL_E = 0 AND COL_F = 0 then fill the rows in COL_A which meet these conditions with a default value of 0.06077.

You probably needs this `case` expression:

```
case when
  coalesce(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D) is null and COL_E = 0 AND COL_F = 1 
  then  0.06077
  else COL_A end as COL_A
```

*Example*

```
with dt as (
select null COL_A, null COL_B, null COL_C, null COL_D, 0 COL_E, 1 COL_F from dual union all
select 1 COL_A, null COL_B, null COL_C, null COL_D, 0 COL_E, 1 COL_F from dual union all
select null COL_A, null COL_B, null COL_C, null COL_D, 0 COL_E, 0 COL_F from dual
)
select 
case when
  coalesce(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D) is null and COL_E = 0 AND COL_F = 1 
  then  0.06077
  else COL_A end as COL_A, 
COL_B, COL_C, COL_D, COL_E, COL_F
from dt;

     COL_A COL_B COL_C COL_D      COL_E      COL_F
---------- ----- ----- ----- ---------- ----------
,06077                                0          1
         1                            0          1
                                      0          0
```